# IIS Dynamic HTTP Response Headers

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api, http-headers

Recently published a JavaScript plugin that various websites embed which depends on a users physical location. We are resolving the location with their IP address via a commercial service when the browser's Geolocation API is not an option.

The problem is we need the location at various times, sometimes not needed at all depending on the users actions, meanwhile the script is sending/receiving JSON data with an ASP.NET Web API solution.

**Wondering how to add the users GeoLocation details to specific endpoint HTTP response headers served from IIS 8?** This would allow for the location to be continuously updated while not adding extra GET requests from the script or modifying request/response models.

1. Would this be best handled with a ASP.NET Module?
2. Ever work with an API's that handle data through headers?
3. Any potential issues with this method (outside of the performance hit of calling location service)?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478420/add-header-to-web-api-actions-on-controller?rq=1) turned out to be an easy and clean way to add the dynamic response header values. Using an action filter made it easy to add to specific API methods.